# Is this a safe way to operate an H-bridge with SPDT relays?

Tags: diodes, motor, relay, dc-motor

[image]

I am trying to create a circuit to drive a hand drill motor as seen in this drawing with just relays. The current formation to make it go forward, switching 2 and 3 at the same time to make it go backwards, and switching 1 to make it stop. I expect it to be ~18V at ~20A when running. Do I need flyback diodes for this to work correctly and if so how would I go making that calculation and selecting that part? When switching 2 and 3 at the same time is there anything I should be concerned about?

Comment: change the state of one of the relays 2 or 3 ... what happens?

Comment: lose relay 1 ..... swap the motor and battery positions ... what do you get now?

Comment: If you connect the motors to the same terminals at once, that would create a short circuit which would be bad and might happen if they don't switch at exactly the same time so I should switch 1 to open when switching 2 and 3 from forward to reverse positions which I figured would be a good idea, but forgot to mention. And for the second question, if you switch doesn't that get the same functionality?

Comment: No - it gives better functionality because of you swap the motor and battery in your circuit then no matter how you switch relays 2 & 3 you can't short out the battery and it removes the need for relay 1.